# Using itemprop attributes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, schema.org

I am making some changes to a cart which was built using AngularJS, one of my tasks is to add itemprop attributes to existing markup eg.

```
<span itemprop="color">{{colourOption.colour.code}}</span>
```

The problem is that this value gets interpolated much later after an Ajax call returns, so any webcrawler or whatever wants to access this itemprop doesn't get the interpolated value, it gets the angular expression instead.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-bind` directive to mask your templating in the event of web-crawlers.

`<div ng-bind='colourOption.colour.code'>This is search-engine friendly text.</div>`

Comment: But I want the interpolated value returned after AngularJS has parsed the template

Comment: You may need to use `Node.js` or a server-side implementation, then.

Comment: I'll +1 you because your answer is useful and we ended up going serverside.